How to generate minimum phase convolutions from Z-space sampling?
As far as I understand it, a convolution is classified as minimum phase if and only if all zeroes and poles from its transfer function lie in the Z-plane unit circle. However, I'm having trouble going from the transfer function to its corresponding convolution.
Let's say we construct the transfer function:
$ 
H(z) = K \cdot \frac{(z - z_1)(z - z_2) \cdots (z - z_n)}{(z - p_1)(z - p_2) \cdots (z - p_m)} 
\text{with } |z_i| \leq 1 \text{ and } |p_i| \leq 1 \text{ for all } i
$ And $K$ is a real constant.
That is, $H(z)$ represents all rational transfer functions with roots and poles inside the unit circle in Z-space.
My goal is to generate the space of all possible minimum phase convolution kernels, or at least a large and representative sub-space. My question is: How do I go from this transfer function to a convolution of size $k$? For a convolution of size $k$, would the degree of the numerator polynomial be equal to $k+1$? Would the automation of this search face any practical problems that I should be aware of (i.e. numerical precision)?

Let' see if we can straighten out the terminology a bit.
"Convolution" is a well defined mathematical operation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) . It's often used to implement FIR filters the impulse response of which is often referred to as a kernel.
$$
H(z) = K \cdot \frac{(z - z_1)(z - z_2) \cdots (z - z_n)}{(z - p_1)(z - p_2) \cdots (z - p_m)} \tag{1}$$
is the transfer function of a linear time invariant system. However, this is generally an IIR filter and can hence NOT be implemented with convolution, unless you truncate and approximate the IIR impulse response with an FIR (which induces error).

How do I go from this transfer function to a convolution of size k

You don't. You can't implement this through convolution. However you can simply multiply out the roots as a polynomial and you will get the transfer function in polynomial form
$$H(z) = \frac{\sum_{K=0}^{N-1}b_kz^{-k}}{\sum_{K=0}^{M-1}a_kz^{-k}} \tag{2}$$
The inverse Z-transform of the transfer function relation $Y{z}=X(z)H(z)$ gives you time domain difference equation
$$b_0x[n] + b_1x[n-1] + ... + b_{n-1}x[n-N+1] = 
a_0y[n] + a_1y[n-1] + ... + a_{n-1}y[n-M+1] $$
This equation can be easily implemented directly in the time domain as
$$y[n] = b_0x[n] + b_1x[n-1] + ... -a_1y[n-1]-a2y[n-2]... $$

Would the automation of this search face any practical problems that I should be aware of (i.e. numerical precision)?

Yes. Finding the roots of a higher order polynomial is a numerically tricky problem and can often lead to noise or instability for poles that are close to the unit circle.
The standard way of implementing this would be cascaded second order section. Each section has order of 2 and is created by pairing a complex pole pair with a complex zero pair (or two real and pole/zeros). Since each section is minimum phase the cascade of all sections is minimum phase too.

I think I see my misconceptions now, thank you! Yes, I was looking for finite kernels. More specifically, I was looking for ways to generate the space of all (or several) stable and causal kernels. I guess sampling from the Z-space unit circle will not work then. Do you have any suggestions on that regard?

You can still sample in the Z-plane. Just use zeros with $|z| \le 1$and set all the poles to $p=0$. That will make it a minimum phase FIR. Whether you will get a useful transfer function with picking random zeros remains to be seen. The space of "all possible" transfer function is huge.
